# "Missing FROM-clause entry" when using nested merges with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to use ActiveRecord queries to select devices belonging to specific users in my DB (devices are just models containing push notifications keys), regarding how many orders users made, or other things.

(In all models I removed non relevant or private stuff)

Here is my Device model:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order
  has_one :device
end
```

Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :order_status
  scope :valid, -> { joins(:order_status).merge(OrderStatus.valid) }
end
```

OrderStatus model:

```
class OrderStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  scope :valid, -> { where.not(name: "processing") }
end
```

So, with all these, i'm trying to get Devices belongings to users who have made more than x valid orders.
Here is where i am:

```
Device.all.joins(:user).merge(User.joins(:order).merge(Order.valid).group("users.id").having("count(orders.id) > ?", [NB_ORDERS]))
```

This generates this request:

```
: SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id"
= "devices"."user_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "order_statuses" ON "order_statuses"."id" = "orders"."order_status_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ("order_statuses"."name" != $1) GROUP BY users.id HAVING count(orders.id) > 10
```

And gives me this error:

> Hirb Error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for
>   table "orders" LINE 1: ... JOIN "order_statuses" ON
>   "order_statuses"."id" = "orders"."...

What i really don't understand is that when i just do

```
User.joins(:order).merge(Order.valid).group("users.id").having("count(orders.id) > ?", [NB_ORDERS])
```

It gives me the right result. It seems like nesting merges messes up with Postgres.

is there a way to solve this problem ? (I have a great amount of records so using SQL/ActiveRecord is essential)

Comment: Why you use `Device.all`? It returns Array not Relation. Try `Device.joins(...)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does return a relation. Anyways, when I remove .all, I get the exact same error

Comment: Can you try with Proc `merge`, i.e. `Device.all.joins(:user).merge(-> { User.joins(:order)... })`?

Comment: Yeah it works ! Thanks a lot :) Can you post this as an answer ? (Some explanations would be greatly appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `merge` as Proc, like

```
Device.joins(:user).merge(-> { User.joins(:order)... })
```

Sorry, right not I cannot give any explanations because I don't know much about `merge` method.
I just read the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) and saw Proc option.

Maybe soon I will dive into the problem and be able to help you with something more than this.